# Transferring scripts from s3 to emr master

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I've managed to get data files distributed on emr clusters, but can't get the simple python scripts copied over to the master instance to run the hadoop job.

Using aws cli (`aws s3 cp s3://the_bucket/the_script.py .`) returns

`A client error (Forbidden) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`.

I tried starting emr clusters from the console, checking `default` in the IAM roles section,

I've setup two IAM roles `EMR_DefaultRole` , `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` making sure they had all `s3` access permissions available,

and I've made sure to run `aws configure` for both `ec2-user` and `hadoop` (confirming the right creds were in `~/.aws/config`).

Still get the error above. If the `hadoop` user can `distcp` the data from the same `s3` bucket that holds my python scripts, shouldn't `hadoop` user be able to copy those scripts using `aws s3`? Isn't the same user (`hadoop`) accessing the same bucket? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: do you know if it's free to transfer from s3 to emr spark cluster?